# Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]

Tags: javascript, angular, error-handling

```
@Injectable()
class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

  handleError(error) {
    // exception occured in some service class method.
    console.log('Error in MyErrorhandler - %s', error);
      if(error == 'Something went wrong'){
       //do this.
     }else{
      //do this thing.
    }
  }
}
```

When in some class' method throws an exception then, the MyErrorHandler class prints the error caught as `Error in MyErrorhandler - Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]
Error: Something went wrong.`

**Question1**: Why does the error displays as `Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]`?

**Question2**: Due to the above message it will always read the else part even in the case of `if(error == 'Something went wrong')`of the code in any condition.How can I resolve this?

Comment: `[object Object]` is returned when `Object.toString()` is called. Most probably `error` is an Object.

Comment: yes, the error is an object, but when I wrote JSON.stringify(error), it displays circular JSON object.

Comment: Try to log keys. `Object.keys(error)`. Mostly, it should be `error.message ===`

Comment: It displays `Array(4)`

Comment: Apologies @Aditya. I cannot help you debug. Try `for(var key in error) { console.log(key + ': ' + error[key])}` You will find what you are looking for

Comment: If it displays Array(4) that means there are 4 properties in the error object, when I console `error.message` it displays same as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding

```
if(error.message == 'Something went wrong'){
}
```

instead of only error. As error is an object.

Comment: when I log console for `error.mssage` it displays `Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Object]
Error: Something went wrong.`

Comment: Can you send me some references on how to get the type of error?I should need here `error:Error`.

Answer (score 2):

is necesary your check the response in yours promise...

you have to capture **resolve** and **reject**...

generally this happens because the value of **reject** not is capture

for example

**CREATE PROMISE...**

```
promise= () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      if (condition) {
         resolve(true);
      }else{
        reject(false);
      }
    });
}
```

**And here capture ALL posible response in promise..**

```
this.services.promise().then(
    (data) => {
       here capture your resolve
       },
    (err) => {
       here capture your resolve
    }
);
```

**OR**

```
 this.services.promise()
   .then((res) => {
       console.log('response in resolve = ', )});
    ).catch((err)=> {
      console.log('response in reject = ', err)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Injectable, ErrorHandler, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertService } from './_alert.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ErroresService implements ErrorHandler {

  constructor(private sv_alert:AlertService) { }
  
  handleError(err:any) { 
    const message = err.message ? err.message: err.message.toString();
    this.sv_alert.AlertaMensajeError(`${ message }`);
  }
}
```